# How to combine two commands in a script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script which works the way it should, on click it bring a div out from the right and when you click the close div it returns back to its original position. It works once but if I try to click more than once it doesn't respond. I know its because of how I have the script laid out so if anyone could show me where I'm going wrong then that would be much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clicked = true;
    $(".open-big").on('click', function () {
        if (clicked) {
            clicked = false;
            $(".expandedImage").css({
                "right": "100%"
            });
        }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clicked = true;
    $(".close-big").on('click', function () {
        if (clicked) {
            clicked = false;
            $(".expandedImage").css({
                "right": 0
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: And put all inside a single `document.ready` function...

Comment: Your `clicked` variables are two separate variables, not the same variable. If you put everything in a single `$(document).ready` function, then you wouldn't have the problem.

Comment: Use hasClass to check current state, toggleClass to change one class on another. Do not use css method, put everything in class.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, you might be interested in [this question on Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265210/372643).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap both event is `document.ready` and use one global flag for both.

you have to write like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var open = true;
    $(".open-big").on('click', function () {
        if (open) {
            open = false;
            $(".expandedImage").css({
                "right": "100%"
            });
        }
    });


    $(".close-big").on('click', function () {
        if (!open) {
            open = true;
            $(".expandedImage").css({
                "right": 0
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you have wrapped both handlers in separate `document.ready` closures so you have 2 instances of `clicked`.

In order to share access to the same `clicked` variable put all the code in one closure with only one `clicked` variable that is in scope for both event handlers

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clicked = false;
    $(".open-big").on('click', function () {
        if (clicked) {
            clicked = true;
            $(".expandedImage").css({
                "right": "100%"
            });
        }
    });


    $(".close-big").on('click', function () {
        if (clicked) {
            clicked = false;
            $(".expandedImage").css({
                "right": 0
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Teemu trying to avoid rewriting the whole method to point out why approach was wrong. Without some html not really sure what will work

Comment: @Teemu you did spot it, I wasn't focusing on the logic as much as format..thx

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var clicked = true;
        $(".open-big").on('click', function(){abcde('100%')};
        $(".close-big").on('click',function(){abcde(0)});
    });

    function abcde(percentage){
          if (clicked) {
                clicked = false;
                $(".expandedImage").css({
                    "right": percentage
                });
            }
    }
    </script>
```

- Use one document.ready.
- Use one global clicked var.
- Use one function with a param to prevent duplicates.

Btw only the first event will run since clicked is true and is in a global scope(I assume you want it that way).

What are you trying to do here?